# jQuery disable checkbox by number in class order

Tags: jquery, class, checkbox

I have a series of checkboxes:

```
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="5" /> 
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="8" /> 
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="10" />  
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="30" />
```

There are several hundred of these (don't ask).

Using jQuery I can enable and disable the checkboxes using `class` but what I need to do is enable/ disable the second and fifth checkbox that appears for `class="Spec"`.

Is it possible, would it child/parent etc?

Comment: 2nd and 5th by index or value

Comment: `$('.Spec').filter(':eq(1), :eq(4)').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: Thanks for the replies - it's by Index.

Comment: whether the above solution is working for you

Comment: @ArunPJohny - yes, as per others below - exactly what I was looking for - thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
 $('.Spec').filter(':eq(1) , :eq(4)').prop('disabled', true);
```

`eq(1)` and `eq(4)` will disables the **second** and **fifth** checkboxes symultaneously.Or individually you can do like

```
$('.Spec:eq(1)').prop('disabled', true);
$('.Spec:eq(4)').prop('disabled', true);
```

It should be like this also

```
$('.Spec').eq(1).prop('disabled', true);
$('.Spec').eq(4).prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector (*based on the index*):

```
$('.Spec:eq(1)').prop('disabled', true);  // disable the second checkbox
$('.Spec:eq(4)').prop('disabled', true);  // disable the fifth checkbox
```

Comment: Didn't realise it was that simple! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best solution is when you set html then add a one class to disable checkbox
like

```
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input class="Spec disclass" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="5" /> 
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="8" /> 
<input class="Spec disclass" type="checkbox" value="10" />  
<input class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="30" />
```

then in Js

```
$(".disclass").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

or you can try if you dont want to add class

```
$('.Spec')
.filter(':eq(1), :eq(4)')
.attr('disabled','disabled');// by attr


 // or can try
 $('.Spec')
    .filter(':eq(1), :eq(4)')
    .prop('disabled',true);
```

reference **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** and **[prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** and **[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

Comment: He hasn't told to add an extra class.

Comment: i think it need to 1 up :) @Homer_J

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS3 nth-child selector. eg. 2nd:

```
$('.Spec>:nth-child(2)').attr("disabled","disabled");
```

similar for 5th checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
//use true to enable and false to disable
    var arrChk = $('.Spec');
    arrChk[1].checked = true;
    arrChk[4].checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$("#button").toggle(function(){
    $( "input:eq(4)" ).attr("checked",true).addClass("selected");
}, function(){
    $( "input:eq(4)" ).attr("checked",false).removeClass("selected");
});
```

attr() or prop(), If you have jquery 1.9.1 => you have to use prop().

http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/WyRfF/

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use following code to disable specific checkbox

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var len = $('.Spec').length;
        var count = 1;
        $( ".Spec" ).each(function() {
            if (count == 2 || count == 5) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            }
            count++;
        });
    });
</script>

You can use following code to enable specific checkbox

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var len = $('.Spec').length;
        var count = 1;
        $( ".Spec" ).each(function() {
            if (count == 2 || count == 5) {
                $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            count++;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Aniket - thank for the reply but the solutions already provided are shorter and cleaner but I do appreciate you taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
$("input.Spec[value=2]").attr('checked', true);
$("input.Spec[value=10]").attr('checked', true);
```

Please note that this will select ALL checkboxes with values 2 and 10 (in case you have more then one checkbox with the same value)

If you don't know the values or don't want this from above then perhaps one other way will be to have auto-generated IDs for your checkboxes like this:

```
<input id="c1" class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input id="c2" class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input id="c3" class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="5" /> 
<input id="c4" class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="8" /> 
<input id="c5" class="Spec" type="checkbox" value="10" />  
...
```

Then have something like this:

```
$("#c2").attr('checked', true);
$("#c5").attr('checked', true);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel but it's the `Index`, not the value I'm looking to enable and disable on.